# trying to download my feed with instaloader

Tags: python, instaloader

Where do I look for this problem?

```
from instaloader import Instaloader, Profile
import instaloader

L = instaloader.Instaloader()
L.load_session_from_file("wetbanana420")

L.download_feed_posts(max_count=20, 
post_filter=lambda post: post.is_video)
```

Comment: Retrieving pictures from your feed...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\wytse\Downloads\Interesting Sh!t-20220909T173618Z-001\Interesting Sh!t\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 7, in <module>
    L.download_feed_posts(max_count=20, post_filter=lambda post: post.is_video)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\instaloader\instaloader.py", line 81, in call
    return func(instaloader, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: Is your session saved correctly? Maybe try L.interactive_login("username") instead of loading the session.

Comment: session is good, I get a loaded session from path notification before the error shows up